# What is the main advantage of GIT over SVN?

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

From my understand of Git Vs SVN, the main advantage of Git over SVN, apart from the distributed nature of Git, is that one can commit/push updates to the remote respository, without having to resolve conflicts at point of updateding the repository.

What do you think?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? The body of your post doesn't really match the title.

Comment: just updated, does that help?

Comment: That's more clear, but this question is probably too opinion based for Stack Overflow. See the [Help/On-Topic].

Answer (score 2):

Speed.

Speed is the PRIMARY advantage. To me, `git` feels like a tool you use like `grep` or `sed` or `awk`. It is something you run without needing to think of the implications.

Hmm.. why does this code look funny? Who wrote it? `git blame`

Hmm.. why did this break things? What did I do wrong? `git diff`

Hmm.. what would happen if I did this? `git branch`

Branching and merging is fast in git so branching becomes another coding strategy just like undoing changes in your IDE or diffing changes between files.

On the other hand, svn feels like a server.

No doubt svn developers have added features that allows svn to do things similar to what git can do. But it will take a minute or so to do most of them. So it doesn't feel like `grep` or `awk` or `ps` or `ls`. It feels more like logging in to your bank account.

Because of this you will use them differently. To me git feels like a regular unix tool. Svn feels like a service. Speed is what makes me use git like a tool rather than just a file server.